# How to use firejail to mount firefox to the encrypted partition

Tags: filesystems, mount-point

If I use cryptsetup to encrypt the / dev/sda4 partition and mount it to the / mnt/encrypted_fs_mnt directory.
Now I want to use firejail to mount firefox to the encrypted partition

But firejail does not seem to have such configuration files and options.

I've tried to use this command to runfirejail --profile=/home/x/.wps.firejail --private=/mnt/encrypted_fs_mnt/firefox  Or use it in the configuration file  mount $HOME/media/encrypted /mnt/encrypted_fs_mnt